# CSS linear gradient with separations

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I need to make dynamic component, looks like that:
[image]

The number of cells (8 in the picture) is dynamic (let's call it X) so I need to support each number of cells (I work with React).

Now, I guess I have two options:

1. Create a long span with the gradient, and in addition create X cells with white border, transparent background, absolute position - and the cells will "cover" the gradient. I already see at least one problem - the background under the gradient might not be always white. Also I'm afraid it will need special alignments on mobile or different browsers.
2. Create X cells with gradient, each cell will have the gradient start (and end) in a different position. But I can't figure out how to do it.

Which solution is better? If solution 2 is better, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using mask and one div:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,green,yellow);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to right,#fff calc(100% - 5px), transparent 0) 
                 0 / calc((100% + 5px)/8) 100%;
          mask: linear-gradient(to right,#fff calc(100% - 5px), transparent 0) 
                 0 / calc((100% + 5px)/8) 100%;
}

body {
  background:#e2e2e2;
  border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can add CSS variables to easily adjust the different values:

```css
.box {
  --n:8;
  --b:5px;

  height:100px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,green,yellow);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to right,#fff calc(100% - var(--b)), transparent 0) 
                 0 / calc((100% + var(--b))/var(--n)) 100%;
          mask: linear-gradient(to right,#fff calc(100% - var(--b)), transparent 0) 
                 0 / calc((100% + var(--b))/var(--n)) 100%;
   margin:5px 0;
}

body {
  background:#e2e2e2;
  border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--n:10;--b:10px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--n:5;--b:15px;"></div>
```

Another syntax:

```css
.box {
  --n:8;
  --b:5px;

  height:100px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,green,yellow);
  -webkit-mask: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
                  #fff        0 calc((100% + var(--b))/var(--n) - var(--b)), 
                  transparent 0 calc((100% + var(--b))/var(--n)));
                 
          mask: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
                  #fff        0 calc((100% + var(--b))/var(--n) - var(--b)), 
                  transparent 0 calc((100% + var(--b))/var(--n)));
   margin:5px 0;
}

body {
  background:#e2e2e2;
  border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--n:10;--b:10px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--n:5;--b:15px;"></div>
```